# Disable absolutely all auto-comments, for real

Tags: vimrc, neovim, autocmd, comments

Auto-comments are the most annoying "feature" of text editors and IDEs for me.

I've searched -- nay, *scavenged* -- high and low to figure out how to get rid of *literally any semblance of automatic comment continuation*, and for whatever reason it's proving impossible and incredibly annoying.

Right now, I have tried the following three lines, which works for most languages.

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead,FileType * set formatoptions-=cro
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead,FileType * setlocal formatoptions-=cro
au FileType c,cpp setlocal comments-=:// comments+=f://
```

But whenever I open a file that isn't considered C++ at first (i.e. not the correct extension) and use `setf cpp`, all auto-comments seem to come back to haunt me.

Even sometimes opening a known-to-be-C++ file, this still happens. I'm not sure what the cause is, but it's aggravating.

**How on Earth can I tell vim that I *really truly* do not want auto-comments, ever, under any circumstances?** I feel like I've been plagued by this for *years*.

Comment: Just to eliminate the obvious first: we are sure that you don't have a plugin which re-enables your autocomments? If you start vim with a vimrc containing only the 3 lines in your questions you still observe the same problem?

Comment: @statox Yeah, I tried that already. This has definitely been a problem since before I knew plugins were even a thing (years ago). Always good to check, though.

Comment: The answer is simple: do **not** enable filetype plugins.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt doesn't that disable coloring as well?

Comment: @Qix no it doesn't.

Comment: No, however in C and C++ cases it'll break matchpair, plugins that rely on `'commentstrings'` to (un)comment blocks of code, and it'll completely disable plugins that define what they provide in ftplugins. For instance, in lh-cpp I define the doxygenating command `:DOX` in an ftplugin. I understand that some default settings don't suit us, however without ftplugins, vim would be quite crippled for programming tasks. They were the huge improvement of Vim 6.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The culprit is `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/c.vim`, and likely all other standard ft plugins. If you want everything they define but the setting for `'formatoptions'`, I don't see any simple solution. (Just in case, `$VIMRUNTIME` is set within vim)

May be, you could listen for `OptionSet` to prevent inserting `cro` in `&fo`. But beware of possible infinite loops. I've never tried it.

BTW, I would have left `'comments'` alone. This option could be used by plugins that toggle comments on blocks, or that generate documentation -- I actually use it in mu-template to insert license captions as comments, which ever the current language is.

Comment: **You are an absolute _god_.** `autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead,FileType,OptionSet * set formatoptions-=cro` and 
`autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead,FileType,OptionSet * setlocal formatoptions-=cro` did it. The struggle is _finally over_. I feel like I can develop again. The bonds of magic text editors have been freed and my fingers feel _liberty_ once again.

Comment: Any chance you could elaborate? I had a quick look in my copy (Vim 7.4) of `c.vim` and can't see anything that's not easily overridden (and I haven't ever had any problems with setting `formatoptions` myself, so I don't really understand what's going wrong.) Why is listening for `OptionSet` necessary in this case?

Comment: @Rich. It's about not overriding every possible standard ftplugins. Yes this is indeed possible, but this requires a lot of work. In a normal scenario, we code in 2-3 programming language and we can then override 2-3 ftplugins, copy everything we like (and the `b:did_filetype` guard), but the formatoption, or even better, let the standard ftplugin do its job, and then cancel in `$HOME/.vim/after/ftplugin/ft1.vim` the setting on `&fo`. We can also in two lines override one standard setting for all filetypes if we really don't like it.

Comment: @Qix, I've cheated. Yesterday I was looking for a `ShellCmdPre` event (which doesn't exist). In the process, I've re^42-discovered `OptionSet`.

Comment: OptionSet has been included in a Vim 7.4 patch. It might not be available in all versions.